# Issues with drop and drag file name in desktop applicaton

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, components, desktop

I have a desktop application done in Java using Swing
I have `JTextField` in which filenames with absolute path are entered.
I am using `JFileChooser` to allow user to select file. Once user selects the file text field is populated with the absolute path of the selected file.
My client wanted to have drag and drop provision to select and insert file name in the text box.

For this I have added following code:

```
public void setdroppedFilePath(javax.swing.JTextField jtf)
    {

        new FileDrop( System.out, jtf, new FileDrop.Listener()
        {
            public void filesDropped( java.io.File[] files)
            {
                if(files.length > 0)
                {
                    String extension = "";
                    String filename  = files[0].getAbsolutePath();
                    int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        extension = filename.substring(i+1);}
                        if (extension.compareTo("rkl")==0){
                            jtf.setText(files[0].getAbsolutePath());
                        }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I use the above function in the mouse enter event of the text field.

```
 private void JTFOriginalFileMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_JTFOriginalFileMouseEntered
        setdroppedFilePath(JTFOriginalFile);
```

This is working ok for my purpose. 
However I did notice that it takes much more time then normal time for execution of the application some time only. Most of the time it works ok  but in some run it takes  a lot of time and eventually execute successfully.

Why is it taking more time in some cases and how I can avoid this?

Application without drag and drop worked very well with out any problem.
I just added these two function to add drag and drop and delay starts happening.
Maybe I am wrong in my approach to add drag and drop provision and can some one please direct me to some link where I can understand better way to add drag and drop to my application.

Comment: Delay occurs for any files, which have been executing normally might cause delay in another run.

Comment: 1) *"Delay occurs.."* Best to [edit] that information into the question, but while you're at it.. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).